# ng2-tag-input separatorKeys not working

Tags: angular, ng2-tag-input

I am trying to use ng2-tag-input module , with a very basic configuration:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search-form',
  template: `<tag-input [(ngModel)]='items'></tag-input>`
})

export class SearchFormComponent {



    items = ['Pizza', 'Pasta', 'Parmesan'];
    options = {
        placeholder: "+ term",
        secondaryPlaceholder: "Enter a new term",
        separatorKeys: [32,13]
    }
    onItemAdded(item) {

    }
    onItemRemoved(item) {

    }


}
```

Everything works, except separatorKeys - it has no effect, when I type *space* key `(keyCode=32)`, it behaves as a normal space instead of a separator.

On the demo page their example works fine, is this something that can be related to NG2 version?

https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-tag-input

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the module.

It does not seem you are setting the separatorKeys attribute in your template. Have a look at http://www.webpackbin.com/NJy38G8kM for the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working... I tried the section of "An input which allows adding items by pressing the key "space" of your keyboard"  in the link you sent and it does not work.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue... doesn't seem to work in the webpackbin in Chrome.

Comment: Hi you're right, I opened a new issue here https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-tag-input/issues/90

Answer (score 0):

add separatorKeys into html template

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search-form',
    template: `<tag-input [(ngModel)]='items'
                          [separatorKeyCodes]="[32,13]"></tag-input>`
})
```